# Continuous functions inner product definition

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, inner-products

If we have two functions F1(x) & F2(x) defined on [x1,x2] then their inner product is $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} F_1(x)F_2(x)dx$ 
The origin of the definition is that F1(x) can be represented as a vector of infinite dimensions each containing F1(x) (the value of F1) at this dimension, so F1(x).F2(x)=$\sum_{x_1}^{x_2} f_{1i} f_{2i} $, so where did the "dx" come from in the integral $\int F_1(x)F_2(x)dx$? what I know is that $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} F_1(x)F_2(x)dx$=$\sum_{x_1}^{x_2} f_{1i} f_{2i} \Delta x$ when $\Delta x \rightarrow\infty$ so how come we convert the product to an integral when the summation doesn't have $\Delta x$ ??

Comment: The limit wouldn't exist without the scaling. Anyway, the infinite sum description is an analogy, really, because a function on an interval is not really an uncountable vector.

Comment: sorry but I don't get it, what do u mean?

Comment: For the first sentence, the infinite sum without rescaling by the shrinking $\Delta x$ would need to actually be a sum of uncountably many terms, since the interval contains uncountably many points. Such a sum would not be finite for basically any $F_1$ and $F_2$. The point of the second sentence is that you are really pushing the motivational analogy too far: the $L^2([a,b])$ inner product is not really a limit of Euclidean inner products. (The limit of the Euclidean inner products is actually the $\ell^2 := L^2(\mathbb{N})$ inner product.)

Comment: well if the inner product is not a limit of euclidean inner products (meaning $F_1(x).F_2(x) not = \sum_{x_1}^{x_2}f_{1i}f_{2i}$ ) then what is its proper definition?

Comment: The integral really is the definition of the inner product.

Comment: u mean that the inner product has two forms, one when the functions are in the vector forms and the other when they are in the ordinary function form?

Comment: It has *many* forms, these are just two distinct examples. You should look up the abstract definition of an inner product.